# Flux Don't output any result

Tags: java, reactor

I started learning java reactor 3. The following code can't output any results.

```
  Flux.create(sink -> {
           
            sink.next("produce a number： " + Math.random() * 100);
            // sink.complete();
        }).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .subscribe(
                      consumer -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + consumer),
                        error -> System.out.println("error！" + error),
                        () -> {
                            System.out.println("task complete！");
                        });
```

Comment: Where is this code? In `main`? I suspect you’re simply not waiting for it to output

Comment: But, I don't have any output in main for this code

Comment: You have to block `main()` until user input `System.in.read();`. Just after this `subscribe()`! you problem that you app exits earlier than an execution happens in your `Flux`

Comment: Ok, That's the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to block `main()` until user input `System.in.read();`. Just after this `subscribe()`! Your problem that you app exits earlier than an execution happens in your `Flux`.